# PHP : Fastest way to load images through a proxy

Tags: php, performance, ssl, proxy

I'm loading some image from a source that is not SSL. In order for this not to break my SSL certificate I have having to load them through this simple PHP proxy page:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');
if(isset($_GET['url'])){echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']);}
?>
```

This works but unfortunately I'm experiencing quite slow load times. **Does anyone know a faster way to proxy images?**

Thanks Guys!

Comment: Passing an unsanitized GET variable to file_get_contents and the like is really not safe.

Comment: Post your server setup (ie. apache, nginx, etc.) I am fairly sure the responses given will be to not use PHP fot this and to use the web server.

Comment: example.com/proxies.php?url=/etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Comment: @Max thanks, what method of sanitization would you recommend?

Comment: @pagewill file_get_contents can load local files aswell. By giving "/etc/apache2/apaceh2.conf" as the url your setup will return the Apache config on your server. Extremely unsafe.

Comment: @Max can you also suggest a solution?

Comment: Demonstration of a security vulnerability. If you don't put security checks in place, they'll be able to read important parts of your hard drive, like your conf files.

Comment: Actually there is no really sane solution to do this if your input can be arbitrary. Best practice: never pass such user supplied variables to file_get_contents or similiar functions. At least enforce that the file exists in a safe/public location where you want it to be.

Answer (score 5):

You could look at X-Sendfile, it would work a bit like this:

```
 $file = '/path/to/images/' . $_GET['url'];
 header('X-Sendfile: ' . $file);
```

but Apache would be handling the process itself rather than the overhead of PHP.

http://codeutopia.net/blog/2009/03/06/sending-files-better-apache-mod_xsendfile-and-php/

http://www.jasny.net/articles/how-i-php-x-sendfile/

Comment: I think this is the best solution

Comment: @pagewill You may need to worry about absolute paths, depends on what $_GET['url'] is storing - I've modified accordingly to make it clearer

Comment: I will setup X-SendFile on my server an post back results

Comment: X-Sendfile needs specific apache configuration: [mod_xsendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/)

Comment: @ADW I am sourcing images from cross-domain, is that ok?